# Unexpected fetch data hook behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning how to fetch data with hook. In my mini project, I create a custom hook to fetch and return the data. In my component, I create 2 different states to store 2 lists from the fetched data, and render them on screen.

Expected result: When i click the name from User List, it will move this user to Delegate List. When I click reset both lists should return to original state.

Actual result: Console.log shows that the original data is modified every time a name is clicked. Therefore i can't reset the lists. I can't explain why the state in useFetchData changes when the component states change.

What did I miss? Thanks! [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usefetchdata-fdk7g?fontsize=14)

Comment: once you populated you hook state the reset button is not working properly, I think you shoud redo you fetch data once you wanna same condition as a reload page.

Comment: Could you explain why the hook state changes? I don't get why changing the component states also changes the hook state.

Comment: onClicking on reset you are actually pushing the present state data

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I thought it's a hook problem, turned out it's my lack of understanding of the spread operator. After reading the doc, I now know that spread operate only copy the first layer of an array or object. If the array or object is multi-dimensional, spread operator won't work. This is why the hook state has been changed.